# Cracking root user: Automating logging into root using "su" from nonroot user

Tags: linux, password, root, expect

I want to write a script that allows me to pass a password to the `su` command. The reason for this is to automate the process of logging into root from nonroot account. From my basic understanding of security, I know the dangers of this. I still need this to try to crack the root user password by reading passwords from a file.

I have heard about using the `expect` command to automate interactions but I do not know how it works, or if it is applicable in this situation. Any information about using `expect` would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that `sudo` is not an option as my user is not on the sudoer list.

Things I've tried
- Passing the password in using pipes
      Didn't work because of `"su must be used from terminal"` type error
- Passing the password using `echo`
      Whatever was echoed would simply show up after the password was entered

Comment: Depending on the OS you might be able to reboot into single user mode and reset the root password. Otherwise, reboot from a live distribution, mount the local installed OS and reset the root password.

Comment: what about `echo "passwd" | sudo -S your_command`?

Comment: @Pandya Generally yes, though the OP did say "Please note that `sudo` is not an option as my user is not on the sudoer list." . :)

Comment: So, you want us to help you break into somebody else's system?

Comment: @terdon Do you think that would work? Given that `su` has a delay on a failed attempt, even with a script you can only test about, say, one password per second (or whatever delay that system uses.) At this rate a brute-force attack is infeasible, unless you have a very good idea of what the password may be and a highly reduced search space. (Trying 100,000 passwords at 1 password/second would already take over a day, and 100,000 is nothing at all, entropy-wise.) I simply found the problem interesting from a technical perspective. :)

Comment: Though, I'm unsure whether several instances of `su` can run in parallel, and to what degree a brute-force attack could thus be parallelized. Any clue?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa none whatsoever. I was hoping the OP would give a benign reason to do this to assuage my fears of wrongdoing.

Comment: Understandable. :)

Comment: @terdon The benign reason is that I forgot my root password. I changed it to something really complicated. Logged off. Forgot it. Instead of trying to remember or reset, I liked the idea of brute forcing and took it as an interesting challenge.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Yes, I have a very good idea what the password looks like. I'm actually pretty sure its one of 10,000 permutations I generated and put in a file. That's why I though it would be a nice challenge even though `su` has a noticeable delay.

Comment: @Lambert I am using Kali Linux, would either of those ideas work?

Comment: @HyperSphere, yes, I'm pretty sure that it will work. Most distributions don't ask for the root password when you boot into single user mode for recovery purposes.

Comment: Ok, I understand why this is not working. My non-root user is not on the sudoer list. Is there a way to add him to the list? If not, is there another way to have the user attempt to login as root without requiring any special permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this "oneline style"

```
expect -c 'spawn su - ;expect Password:;send "your-password\n";interact'
```

Take a look at the output of `su -` to guarantee if this is the right phrase that appears to capture a password. I'm using a translated version of Linux here so, the word would be "Senha:" instead of "Password:".

- `expect -c ''`: Run the following actions to this command
- `spawn su -`: Execute this command
- `expect Password:` Expect the word password to do something
- `send "your-password\n"`: Type in your password, followed by an Enter
- `interact`: Keep interaction ready to the command.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much for the clear dissection of the commands.

Comment: Ok, I understand why this is not working. My non-root user is not on the sudoer list. Is there a way to add him to the list? If not, is there another way to have the user attempt to login as root without requiring any special permissions?

Comment: If you have the root password, you can use `su - ` to get a root shell. To add people to the sudoers list, you will need to first access the system as root and execute the `visudo` command to grant some privileges that will require(or not) a password. It would be a system failure if you could get root access whenever you want(and without using exploits/bugs), dont you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect` to do that job for you. Save the following to a file, make it executable, and run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn su
expect "Password:"
send "YOUR_PASS\n"
interact
```

(Obviously, you need to specify the correct path to `expect`. Here I used `/usr/bin/expect` as an example.)

If `YOUR_PASS` is the correct root password, you should now have a root shell. If not, you get an authentication failure.

Note that the `interact` command will probably not be needed in the context of a fully automated script, as it gives control of the process to the user, i.e., keystrokes are sent to the current process and stderr and stderr are returned.

See `man expect` for a more detailed description of the commands `spawn`, `expect`, `send` and `interact`, and many other commands.

Comment: Thank you, great help. Quick question though, why does the answer above not require the specification of a file directory for expect and this one does?

Comment: @HyperSphere This is an executable script, and the kernel needs to need what interpreter it should use in order to execute it. This is why it begins with the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!`, followed by the path to the interpreter. The other answer executes the command `expect` in the context of a shell, such as bash. If no path is given, the shell will look for an executable named `expect` in all directories specified in the environment variable `$PATH`, and execute the first it finds with the given arguments.

Comment: The two answers are actually pretty much the same, only written in a slightly different way. Both allow you to execute the expect script in the context of a larger shell script: Either by calling the expect script above, or by using the one-liner from the other answer. Both are fine. A self-contained expect script is probably better for more complex scripts, while the one-liner is easier for simple scripts.

Comment: Ok, I understand why this is not working. My non-root user is not on the sudoer list. Is there a way to add him to the list? If not, is there another way to have the user attempt to login as root without requiring any special permissions?

Comment: What exactly "is not working" for you? In the above script, `su` is used to attempt to login as root; no special privileges are needed to do that, save the root password (in particular, you do not need to be in the sudoers list, which is only relevant for the `sudo` command.) If you could just add yourself to the sudoers list, then you could also just make yourself root without the root password.