# Kali Linux: Non root user logging in as root WITHOUT special permissions

Tags: login, kali-linux, root

I am looking for a command that would allow me to log in as root from a non root account which has no permissions. I cannot add the non root to `sudoers`. Actually can't access root at all. Is there a command for this? Would logging in from root terminal, the program, require special permissions?

Thank you

Comment: What does "can't access root at all" mean? That you are not allowed to change the configuration? The whole permission system would be quite useless if a user without any privileges could just run "a program" ro get root privilege. The "program" you are looking for is called "local root exploit"...

Comment: I changed the password for my root and forgot it immediately. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253584/cracking-root-user-automating-logging-into-root-using-su-from-nonroot-user

Comment: From the sounds of it "local root exploit" is exactly what I was after. You are right the whole permission system would be useless, that is very obvious, I was looking for a way around it as a type of challenge, sorry for not being clear about that part but I wanted to spare the unnecessary details

Comment: Many answers have been provided. I suggest you look into chroot

Answer (score 1):

From your follow-up comments, it becomes clear that what you're really after is a way to recover your root password. This is easy:

- Reboot your system.
- When you see the grub menu, hit 'e' to get an editor.
- in the editor, find the line that starts with `linux`
- at the end of that line, add `init=/bin/bash`.
- hit `ctrl`+`x` to boot the system once with this modified configuration.
- the boot process will be very much incomplete, and not really a working system, but you do get a shell.
- enter the following sequence of commands:

  ```
  mount -o remount,rw / # make the root fs writable
  passwd # change root user's password
  mount -o remount,ro / # make the root fs nonwritable again
  exec /sbin/init # boot normally
  ```

**note**: the minimal boot with bash as init does *not* change your keyboard layout, so it will remain at the default of US QWERTY. Don't forget this when entering your password...

Comment: This *will* fail if some funky stuff (LVM, encryption, load special drivers) needs to be done.

Comment: @vonbrand not true. If the root filesystem requires such things, you need an initramfs whose responsibility it is to set that up. Changing the init binary on the kernel command line does not change the initramfs in any form or shape. Of course, if you need something on a partition that is not mounted by the initramfs, you still have work to do, but that isn't needed for a simple password change.

Answer (score 0):

All Unix/Linux systems have some sort of "rescue" environment, which logs in root for maintenance in a minimalist environment. Sometimes the best way to do this (e.g., for Fedora) is to boot installation media for rescue. This works even if you ***really*** made a mess. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. reboot system
2. hit rapidly "e"
3. you get in editor mode
4. find line which start with linux
5. then change ro to rw and add init=/bin/bash
6. press F10
7. then type passwd
8. change your password